# Funky PHP Namespace Not Resolving

Tags: php, namespaces

I've got an infuriating problem with PHP namespaces that should be incredibly simple, but has consumed about a days worth of work.

Here's the layout:

The directory structure:

```
/site

    /classes
            /cache.php
    /index.php
```

cache.php is as follows:

```
<?
    namespace {
        class Cache {...}
    }
?>
```

index.php consists of:

```
<?php
    namespace {
        \Cache::get()->activate();
    }
?>
```

I've tried about a million different ways of namespacing this, but index.php never has visibility to the Cache class. Surely this should take about 5 seconds to figure out, right?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Thanks for the suggestions!

I've created a cachetest.php page with the following code:

```
namespace {
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . './classes');
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . './libraries/oauth-php');
    spl_autoload_register(function ($name) {
        spl_autoload($name);
    });

    $cache = \Cache::get();
}
```

Still crapping out with an "Fatal error: Class 'Cache' not found" error though. So bizarre given that the autoloader will register other classes in the same directory without a problem.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have an autoloader in place.

Comment: What autoloaders are you using? If you use none, that's your problem. PHP has no magic autoloading rules, you have to register an autoloader. There are many existing one out there, I'd suggest looking at using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org), as that will give you a log of flexibility.

Comment: Why are you declaring your classes as unnamespaced? Might as well not use namespaces at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems.

1. You have no namespaces at all here. That's how you declare a namespace: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php
2. You have no autoloader in place. You must either `require_once('../classes/Cache.php);` or make a (preferably PSR-compliant) autoloader script and register it with `spl_autoload_register()`.

Comment: Thanks, I had a sneaking suspicion that namespace syntax might not be correct.  But shouldn't the cachetest.php code autoload and allow references to the Cache in classes/cache.php. The truly odd thing is that there are a bunch of other classes in classes/ that are resolving just fine. It's only Cache that triggers the exception...

Comment: Try naming the file holding the Cache class *exactly* like the class itself: "Cache.php", starting with uppercase letter. Probably your autoloader (whatever it is) is searching for files case-sensitively.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer was that PHP on windows is extremely sensitive to odd control characters or something. I eventually solved the class resolution problem by commenting out every line in the file, then carefully cutting and pasting them back in--which seemed to eliminate whatever hidden garbage was keeping the autoloader from doing it's stuff.  Pretty awful.